# Finding a basis for a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let U be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$ defined by: 
$U=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5): x_1=3x_2,  x_3=7x_4\}$
Find a basis for $U.$

What I have figured out so far is that all vectors of the subspace are of the form $(3x_2,x_2,7x_4,x_4,x_5).$ So the shape of each of these vectors is dictated by the second, fourth and fifth coordinates. From this, I figure that a basis of this subspace would need only three vectors: $\{(3,1,0,0,0), (0,0,7,1,0), (0,0,0,0,1)\}.$

Is this correct? Is there a computation way to do this? I'm a little apprehensive of creating a matrix because I only have one vector! Would the matrix involve using the coordinates as "column vectors"? I hope this was not too confusing.

Comment: I'd suggest that you read this page http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference on how to format your equation in TeX style.

Comment: I think it just remains to prove every vector in $U$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in your basis and that (the vectors in your basis) are linearly independent.

Comment: @BigbearZzz Thank you for that link. I'll read it for future posts.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculations are correct. If you want to write it more formally, you could write something like that:
$$ U \begin{array}[t]{l}=\{ (3x_2, x_2, 7x_4,x_4, x_5): x_2,x_4,x_5 \in \mathbb R\}\\
=\{x_2\cdot \underbrace{(3,1,0,0,0)}_{\vec {e}_1}+ x_4\cdot \underbrace{(0,0,7,1,0)}_{\vec{e}_2} + x_5\cdot \underbrace{(0,0,0,0,1)}_{\vec{e}_3}: x_2,x_4,x_5 \in \mathbb R\}
\end{array}
$$

Thus, $U = \langle \vec{e}_1, \vec{e}_2, \vec{e}_3 \rangle$ (which means that the 3 vectors span the subpace $U$). Now, you have to prove that the 3 vectors are linearly independent and thus the 3 vectors form a basis of $U$.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I felt like there was something missing. Once I have demonstrated that these vectors are linearly independent and that all the vector of the subspace look like the above, then I have demonstrated that the list of vectors forms a basis!

Comment: But doesn't a spanning set require at least 5 elements for it to span this space of $\mathbb R^{5}$?

Comment: @Jaigus No, we need a set of at least 5 vectors to span the whole $\mathbb{R}^5$ (exactly 5 of them are linearly independent).

Answer (score 0):

Your subspace has vectors of the form $ \vec v= (3x_2, x_2, 7x_4, x_4, x_5)$

Can you find a basis from here?