# How can I find a basis for a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U$ be the subspace $\mathbb R^{5}$ defined by $U$ = {($x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$) $\in$ $\mathbb R^{5}$: $x_1 = 3x_2$,   and $x_3 = 7x_4$

How can I go about finding a basis for $U$?

Comment: Pick an arbitrary nonzero vector $x_1$ in $U$. Does it span $U$? Then you have a basis. No? Pick $x_2$ not in the span of $x_1$. Does $\{x_1,x_2\}$ span $U$? Then you have a basis (why?). No? Then pick $x_3$ not in the span. Lather, rinse, repeat, and think about how you know the process will end and you won’t starve like the computer scientist who read the instructions on the shampoo bottle and stayed in the shower until he died...

Comment: Find a textbook that explains how to do this and read it. Then, if you're still stuck, ask here about what's confusing you. But please do not expect Math.SE to serve as a replacement for a textbook.

Comment: Also, this [exact same question was asked here before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725484/finding-a-basis-for-a-subspace?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general rule of thumb. You have added $2$ linear restrictions to a $5$ dimensional space, so you should get a $3$ dimensional subspace (in general you have to be careful the restrictions are not redundant!)

Based on the restrictions, we know that $x_1$ and $x_2$ must be related to one another, and that $x_3$ and $x_4$ must be related to one another. Perhaps you could find a basis of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
*\\*\\0\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\*\\*\\0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\0\\0\\*
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you, I got { (3,1,0,0,0), (0,0,7,1,0), (0,0,0,0,1) }. But wouldn't the set of vectors in $\mathbb R^{5}$ require at least 5 elements for it to be linearly independent?

Comment: @Jaigus No;  you should review the definition of linear independence

Comment: Ah; its "at most". I usually get this and the def. of span confused lol.

Answer (score 1):

Informally speaking, the dimension of a basis is the minimum number of basis vectors needed to span the entire subspace. Because neither $x_2$ or $x_4$ adds a dimension to the subspace, you are now working with ${(x_1,x_3,x_5)}$, which has a maximum dimension of $3$.

You could now use the Gram-Schmidt process to get an orthogonal basis.